# Why can a function pointer be called without deferencing it?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

If I have the following code example,

```
...

typedef void (*printer_t)(int);

int main()
{
    printer_t p = &print_int;
    p(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does both `p(5);` and `(*p)(5);` output the desired behaviour of printing 5?
If I have a pointer to a function, is that not first required to be dereferenced and then be called, i.e. `(*p)(5);` was the correct behaviour? How does `p(5);` not result in an error by trying to use a calling operation on a memory address location?

Comment: Pointers to functions are unusual. You could get the address of `print_int` with just plain `print_int`, with `&print_int`, with `&&print_int`, etc. And you can call through that pointer with `p(5)`, with `(*p)(5)`, `(**p)(5)`,  `(***p)(5)`, etc. Everything collapses.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can a function pointer be called without deferencing it?

Because the standard says that you can.

> is that not first required to be dereferenced

There is no need to explicitly use the indirection operator, no.